# Как включить в отчёт jacoco все java-пакеты всех проектов .gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

Использую плагин Jacoco для gradle. В проекте несколько .gradle проектов. Тесты запускаются из одного .gradle проекта для всех остальных .gradle проектов. В отчёт jacoco попадают только те пакеты, которые есть .gradle проекте, откуда запускаются тесты. Сделать так, чтобы в отчёт jacoco попадали все пакеты?

Answer (score 0):

Создать глобальный task на сбор общего отчёта. В task прописать

```
additionalSourceDirs = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
classDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.output)
dependsOn = subprojects.test
executionData = files(subprojects.jacocoTestReport.executionData)
sourceDirectories = files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
onlyIf = {
        true
    }

    doFirst {
        executionData = files(executionData.findAll {
            it.exists()
        })
    }
```